# DocuSign VBA Error 400 errorCode: ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE

Tags: docusignapi

You help would be greatly appreciated to understand what then .setRequestHeader setting should be for this error.

```
Public Sub SignatureReq()
Dim httpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

' defined request and result variables
Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP60

' define the new URL for the signature request using the Base URL returned aboved appended with '/envelopes'
Dim sigURL As String
sigURL = URLBase & "/envelopes"
' currently sig URL is 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[account number]'

Dim Body As String
      Body = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\" & Chr(34) & "http://www.docusign.com/restapi\" & Chr(34) & ">" + _
            "<accountId>MyAccountID</accountId>" + _
            "<status>sent</status>" + _
            "<emailSubject>DocuSign API Call - Signature request from template</emailSubject>" + _
            "<templateId>MyTemplateID</templateId>" + _
            "<templateRoles>" + _
            "<templateRole>" + _
            "<name>Ronco</name>" + _
            "<email>rolsen@myemail.com</email>" + _
            "<roleName>Rono</roleName>" + _
            "</templateRole>" + _
            "</templateRoles>" + _
            "</envelopeDefinition>"


Debug.Print Body

httpRequest.Open "POST", sigURL, False

httpRequest.setRequestHeader Body, "application/xml"
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "X-DocuSign-Authentication", Author
'httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
'httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
httpRequest.send

Debug.Print httpRequest.Status, "A"
Debug.Print httpRequest.statusText, "B"
Debug.Print httpRequest.responseText, "C"

Exit Sub
```

The response message is below. I understand the error is coming from the `.setRequestHeader` not being set correctly. Where can I find how the header and values are needed to be set for each `.setRequestHeader` that `DocuSign` will accept?

> 400           Bad Request    {   "errorCode":
>   "ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE",   "message": "The Envelope is not Complete.
>   A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a
>   Subject Line. Content-Type does not contain boundary parameter." }

Comment: So to answer your code problem, use application/xml for your header and not the multipart. Multipart is only used when you have JSON/XML + FILES. Each call in REST support JSON/XML. Some calls support additional formatting such as multipart. This doesn't fully answer your question, so I'm leaving it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When sending a signature request from a Template the `Content-Type` for the API call needs to be set to either `application/json` or `application/xml`.  It looks like you've currently got that commented out and are sending a `multipart/form-data` request.  Comment that line out and add back in:

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
```

If that doesn't work or you've already tried that I recommend enabling **Request Logging** through your developer account Preferences and examining the raw request that's being set to make sure your code is generating what you expect.